# Retrieve created NuGet package filename from 'nuget pack' command?

Tags: nuget

I'm writing a script that will automatically pack and publish Nuget files to my private repository (a fileshare) and a private symbol server (on localhost).

When I run `nuget pack` in Powershell I get a string output that contains the file location of both the nuget and symbol package, but as far as I can tell there's no way to *programmatically* get those paths without parsing the string. The package version is determined by the .csproj itself, so I don't necessarily know which version will be placed in the filename.

Here's the output from the pack command:

```
Attempting to build package from 'MyProject.csproj'.
Building project 'C:\Users\me\prg\MyProject.csproj' for target framework '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0'.
Packing files from 'C:\Users\me\prg\bin\Release'.
Using 'Myproject.nuspec' for metadata.
Successfully created package 'C:\nuget\MyProject.1.0.0.0.nupkg'.

Attempting to build symbols package for 'MyProject.csproj'.
Building project 'C:\Users\me\prg\MyProject.csproj' for target framework '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0'.
Packing files from 'C:\Users\me\prg\bin\Release'.
Using 'MyProject.nuspec' for metadata.
Successfully created package 'C:\nuget\Myproject.1.0.0.0.symbols.nupkg'.
```

Should I just bite the bullet and write some regex to parse out the "successfully created package" lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default `nuget pack` will output the created packages to the current directory. You can override this by specifying the `OutputDirectory` option. It is not clear to me from where you run the `nuget` command (be it from within *C:\Users\me\prg\*, *C:\nuget\*, or somewhere else), so you might already know this, but it can offer you an alternative option:

You can create yourself a temporary directory (e.g. *C:\nuget\temp\*), which you can specify as your `OutputDirectory` option. If you then in your script make sure that this directory is empty before you run `nuget pack`, your can simply copy **.nupkg* to your fileshare (and then afterwards move it to *C:\nuget\*, if that is required).

Comment: Yeah, `OutputDirectory` is what I use now, the only issue is that I need the code package and symbols package to go into different directories (actually, the symbols to an http server).

Temporary folder... now there's an idea.

Comment: @nemec: if you go with the temporary folder, you can begin by moving **.symbols.nupkg* to your symbols server. That would leave only the actual packages in the temp folder, and you can finish up by moving **.nupkg* to your NuGet fileshare, with no need to mess around with regex to match the exact file name etc.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing the output in powershell is not too hard.

```
$a = nuget pack .\Exceptional.csproj -Prop Configuration=Release |  Select-String nupkg
$a -Replace "^[^']'", "" -Replace "'[^']$", ""
```

gives

> C:\Users\phelan\workspace\Exceptional\Exceptional\Weingartner.Exceptional.1.2.6011.19372.nupkg

Comment: How to get it in post-build event?

Answer (score 1):

I made a slight change to the answer provided by @bradgonesurfing as his partly worked for me.

```
$pack = . $nugetPath pack rest of command........ |  Select-String nupkg 
$pack -match "'(?<nupkg>.*)'"
$packageFile = $Matches["nupkg"]
```

To get it in a post build event, I would use the powershell.exe to shell out to a powershell script. I have an example here that I used to automate running editbin that can be modified for nuget: https://gist.github.com/tcartwright/cc1bd4dc98349579630c43283c5f1fe9