# How can I run nuget add on the file generated from nuget pack without knowing the nupkg file name?

Tags: c#, nuget

In my CI build I generate a NuGet package from a .nuspec file using `nuget pack mypackage.nuspec`.  The .nuspec file is updated by the build process using an externally-generated number, meaning the resulting .nupkg file name is different for every build (e.g. `mypackage.1.0.0-alpha1337.nupkg` where `1337` is the externally-generated number).

I have a local feed that uses a [hierarchical folder structure](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/hosting-packages/local-feeds#initializing-and-maintaining-hierarchical-folders), meaning I need to use the `nuget add` command to add the package to the feed.

Unfortunately, the `nuget add` command requires the name of the `.nupkg` file, which is different for every build.  The CI system does not know at build time the externally-generated number (a separate tool handles that) so it has no way to know the nupkg file name.

How can I pass the name of the `.nupkg` file generated by `nuget pack` into the `nuget add` command?  Or, better yet, is there a single command that can handle both `pack` and `add`?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17244893/2561985) does not work because `nuget add` does not support wildcards.